# the collapsible-set & data-filter are not work concurrently

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, user-interface

how to use   data-role="listview"  data-autodividers="true"  data-filter="true"  data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search For Names..."  in ul tag...
i cant able use data-filter and  data-role="listview"  data-autodividers="true" concurrently...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
            <div data-role="content">
                <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
                <ul  data-role="listview"  data-autodividers="true"  data-filter="true"  data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search For Names..." >
                    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                        <li data-role="collapsible">
                            <h3>Adele </h3>
                            <h5>098039847098</h5>
                            <h5>098039847098</h5>   
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="collapsible">
                            <h2>Agnes</h2>
                            <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                            <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                        </li>   
                        <li data-role="collapsible">
                            <h2>Bgnes</h2>
                            <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                            <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                        </li>   
                        <li data-role="collapsible">
                            <h2>Bakgnes</h2>
                            <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                            <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                        </li>   
                    </div>
                </ul>



                <p>The text inside the search box now says "Search For Names...".</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">  </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>My Phonebook</h2>
            <ul  data-role="listview"  data-autodividers="true"  data-filter="true"  data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search For Names..." >
                    <li data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Adele </h3>
                        <h5>098039847098</h5>
                        <h5>098039847098</h5>   
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Agnes</h2>
                        <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                        <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                    </li>   
                    <li data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Bgnes</h2>
                        <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                        <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                    </li>   
                    <li data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Bakgnes</h2>
                        <a href="demo.asp" data-ajax="false">098039847098</a>
                        <h5>098039847098</h5>       
                    </li> 
            </ul>
            <p>The text inside the search box now says "Search For Names...".</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have removed only <div data-role="collapsible-set"> under ul tag, its working fine.

Comment: What you want to say?

Comment: answers should be [clear and comprehensive](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Adding code with no explanation whatsoever could be flagged as _low quality answer_.

Comment: i want to use of <div data-role="collapsible-set"> ...its will be there ..u cant remove it..

Comment: <div data-role="collapsible-set"> after "ul" restrict search filter functionality, if you want to <div data-role="collapsible-set"> use there, so need to create your custom search functionality.